# How to get upper paths from a single path?

Tags: python, directory

How to get upper paths from a single path?

So say you have a path like:

```
'C:\a\b\c\d\'
```

How do I get to `'C:\a\b'` or `'C:\a\b\c'`

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html)

```
from os import path
path.dirname("C:\\a\\b\\c\\d\\")
```

Comment: No, you would refer to it as path.dirname if you did 'from os import path'.

Answer (score 4):

Theres basic stuff like [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) methods.

If you want a list of the full path names of each successive parent in the directory tree, heres a one liner:

```
from os.path import dirname

def f1(n): return [n] if n == dirname(n) else [n] + f1(dirname(n))

print f1("/a/b/c/d/e/f/g")
```

Answer (score 2):

`os.path.split("C:\\a\\b\\c")` will return a tuple:

```
('C:\a\b', 'c')
```

You can continue to call split on the first element of the tuple.

Comment: you are duplicating the functionality of a standard library, which id more robust (what if a path ends in '\' with your example?) and more portable (your example does not work under linux)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def go_up(path, n):
...     return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(*([path] + ['..']*n)))
>>> path = 'C:\\a\\b\\c\\d\\'
>>> go_up(path, 2)
'C:\\a\\b'
>>> go_up(path, 1)
'C:\\a\\b\\c'
>>> go_up(path, 0)
'C:\\a\\b\\c\\d'
```

Not being a regular user of [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html), I don't know if this is an appropriate/pythonic solution. I compared it to an alternate function, define as follows:

```
def go_up_2(path, n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        path = os.path.split(path)[0]
    return path
```

The first thing to note is that `go_up_2('C:\\a\\b\\', 1) != go_up_2('c:\\a\\b', 1)`, where it does with the original `go_up`. However, performance is significantly better, if that is an issue (probably not, but I was looking for some definitive way to say my own algorithm was better):

```
import timeit

g1 = """import os.path
import ntpath
os.path = ntpath
def go_up(path, n):
    return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(*([path] + ['..']*n)))"""

g2 = """import os.path
import ntpath
os.path = ntpath
def go_up(path, n):
    for i in xrange(n-1):
        path = os.path.split(path)[0]
    return path"""

t1 = timeit.Timer("go_up('C:\\a\\b\\c\\d', 3)", setup=g1).timeit()
t2 = timeit.Timer("go_up('C:\\a\\b\\c\\d', 3)", setup=g2).timeit()

print t1
print t2
```

This outputs (on my machine):

```
133.364659071
30.101334095
```

Not very useful information, but I was playing around, and figured it should be posted here anyway.